# Can't understand an expression

Tags: expressions

I was reading "Letters to a Young Contrarian" by Christopher Hitchens. In the preface, he writes a sentence which I can't understand fully.

> ... I thought I would write you a *closing letter by way of beginning*.

What does this expression mean? I tried to search it over the internet and tried understanding it comparing to my own language but I can't understand it clearly. Can anyone help me understand what he means here?

Comment: a letter at the end of something non-specified as a way to begin something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is paradoxical.

A closing letter is a final letter in any correspondence.

Hitchens is saying that he will begin by writing a closing letter (a letter that finalises the matter). He is deliberately using a construction that surprises the reader - for the sake of effect. To understand the matter better, we would have to know more about the context.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox

Comment: "The sentence is paradoxical" - it is to a contrarian, isn't it?